Invalid certificate verification context when calling X509_verify_cert in openSSL
I'm trying to validate a peer cert on a server using a crl in tls but I'm getting "invalid certificate verification context" when calling X509_verify_cert. I've set up my TLS server as below. Why is it giving me this error?
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
ERR_load_crypto_strings();
FILE *fp = fopen(crlPath.c_str(), "r");
crl = PEM_read_X509_CRL(fp, NULL, NULL, NULL);
store = X509_STORE_new();
X509_STORE_load_file(store, caCertPath.c_str());
X509_STORE_add_crl(store, crl);

const SSL_METHOD *method;
SSL_CTX *sslCtx;
method = TLS_server_method());
sslCtx = SSL_CTX_new(method);

SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(sslCtx, serverCertPath.c_str(), SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(sslCtx, serverKeyPath.c_str(), SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);

struct sockaddr_in cli;
len = sizeof(cli);
int conn_fd = accept(serv_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&cli, &len);

ssl = SSL_new(sslCtx);
SSL_set_fd(ssl, conn_fd);

SSL_accept(ssl);
X509 * peerCert = SSL_get1_peer_certificate(ssl);
storeCtx = X509_STORE_CTX_new();
X509_STORE_CTX_init(storeCtx, store, peerCert, NULL);
int res = 0;
if((res = X509_verify_cert(storeCtx)) <= 0)
{
  const char * charErr = X509_verify_cert_error_string(X509_STORE_CTX_get_error(storeCtx));
  printf("%s\n", charErr);
}

